# Beamer: Warsaw style biliography colors

Tags: beamer, text-decorations

In *Beamer*, I am using *Warsaw* style. In bibliography, I use `\newblock` for different type of entries (author, title, journal, ect.). Where can I learn the *colour* information about these structures (in which file, at which line)?
For instance, when I mention an author's name in text, I want to colour the name with the same colour as it appears in the *bibliography*.

Comment: I have found by searching in *google* that the *authorname* color is defined by `%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0.2,0.2,0.7}` hence using `\textcolor{beamer@blendedblue}{AuthorName}` does the job. But I don't know how can I find where this color set for *bibliography*. I also don't know the name of the  light purple colour which is used for the journal name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant information can be found in Section **10.6 Adding a Bibliography** of the `beamer` manual. The relevant colors/templates/fonts you are looking for are

- `bibliography entry author`
- `bibliography entry title`
- `bibliography entry location`
- `bibliography entry note`

If you want to see the actual definitions governing the bibliography, you can see the file `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. There, one finds, for example:

```
\def\beamer@newblock{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}%
  \def\newblock{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}%
    \def\newblock{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}%
      \def\newblock{%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}}}}%
  \leavevmode\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{}\ht\beamer@tempbox=1.5em\box\beamer@tempbox}
```

Each theme can redefine these colors/templates/fonts as desired. Most themes use the definitions of the default theme. For example, for the involved colors, one has (in the file `beamercolorthemedefault.sty`):

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!65!bg}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!65!bg}
```

Notice that, in order to use these colors, you don't need to know the exact color definitions (model, etc.). If you want to use these attributes, then you can use `\usebeamercolor`, `\usebeamerfont`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliography colors}
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}
\usebeamerfont{bibliography entry author}Author}

{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}
\usebeamerfont{bibliography entry title}Title}

{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry location}
\usebeamerfont{bibliography entry location}Location}

{\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}%
\usebeamerfont{bibliography entry note}Note}

\begin{thebibliography}{Dijkstra, 1982}
\bibitem[Dijkstra, 1982]{Dijkstra1982}
E.~Dijkstra.
\newblock Smoothsort, an alternative for sorting in situ.
\newblock {Science of Computer Programming}, 1(3):223--233, 1982.
\newblock{London}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have just figured out that using `\newblock`s apply the same colours. `{\newblock {Author} \newblock {Title} \newblock {Location}}`

Comment: Is it possible to get the text in the first (author name) or the second (title) `\newblock` just by using *reference number*?

Comment: @bkarpuz it all depends on how you build the bibliography; building it "by hand", using the `thebibliography` environment, this is not possible. Building it using `BibTeX` or `biblatex` this is easy. You can open a fresh new question about this.